# Batch Class is not running properly

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch

I have a batch class that will send mail if Opportunity Expiry Date (Custom Field) is Today. I have tried a batch class but it isn't working for me. Can someone tell me how to achieve this.

```
//Batch Class
​​​​​​​global class OpportunityExpiryDate_New implements DataBase.Batchable <sObject> {
    global DataBase.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Expiry_Date__c FROM Oppportunity WHERE Expiry_Date__c = TODAY';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope) {
        messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        for(Opportunity opp : scope) {
            String body = 'The Opportunity'+opp.Name+'is expiring today.';
            email.setToAddresses(new String[]{'maddulasaivineeth@gmail.com'});
            email.setSubject('Opportunities Expiring Today');
            email.setPlainTextBody(body);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be _specific_ about your issue. Please describe exactly how this class is not functioning as expected.

Comment: Your `Oppportunity` keyword is wrong. It should be `Opportunity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main problems here.

First, you're limited to how many emails you can send daily, unless emailing a user.

Second, you're calling Messaging.sendEmail in a loop. This will fail if you make this call more than 10 times in a transaction.

Side note, do not use a query for a string when an inline query will suffice.

---

```
​​​​​​​global class OpportunityExpiryDate_New implements DataBase.Batchable <sObject> {
    global DataBase.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT Name FROM Oppportunity WHERE Expiry_Date__c = TODAY
        ]);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
        User recipient = [select id from user where email = 'maddulasaivineeth@gmail.com' and isactive = true limit 1];
        for(Opportunity opp : scope) {
            messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String body = 'The Opportunity'+opp.Name+'is expiring today.';
            email.setTargetObjectId(recipient.Id);
            email.setSubject('Opportunities Expiring Today');
            email.setPlainTextBody(body);
            messages.add(email);
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }
}
```

---

As another side note, you could do this with a Process Builder's Scheduled Action. Simply configure a Process to send an email on the Expiry Date.